# Using rest-api-connector in node.js - uuid is not defined

Tags: node.js, api, loopbackjs

I am trying to connect to rest API using node and rest-api-connector
connecting to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.co/posts

I am getting an error: ReferenceError: uuid is not defined

Here is example:
https://runkit.com/embed/rxt9h5tj8irn

```
   var api = require('rest-api-connector').api;

//Setup and compile the api node module
api.buildFromJson(
  { //define the api connection info
    API_CFG: {
      BASE_URL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" //api url
    }
  },
  { //define the api definition
    apiCall: {
      url:"/posts/:uuid",
      method: "GET",
      input: [
        { "postId":"1" }
      ]
    }
  }
);

//This is where you use the api module 
api.apiCall(uuid, function(e,r,d){
  console.log(d);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the problem is as it states, you are not defining a `uuid` anywhere.

When you call you need to actually pass the value of a `uuid`. e.g.

```
//This is where you use the api module 
api.apiCall(1, function(e,r,d){
  console.log(d);
});

//"{\n \"userId\": 1,\n \"id\": 1,\n…m sunt rem eveniet architecto\"\n}"

//This is where you use the api module 
api.apiCall(99, function(e,r,d){
  console.log(d);
});

//"{\n \"userId\": 10,\n \"id\": 99,…s nihil\\nitaque dolorem quia\"\n}"
```